# Write text to file from multiple instances of a textbox control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text, textbox, text-files

I have the following code

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
                textbox = New TextBox

                textbox.Size = New Size(50, 50)
                If Controls.Count > 0 Then
                    TextBox.Top = Controls(Controls.Count - 1).Bottom

                End If

                Me.SplitContainer2.Panel1.Controls.Add(textbox)
 End Sub
```

What that does is add instances of textbox one after the other.

The next one writes a text file to my system.

```
Private Sub Button6_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Pantheo\test2.txt"

        If File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then

            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

            objWriter.Write(textbox.Text)
            objWriter.Close()
            MsgBox("Text written to file")

        Else

            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")

        End If
    End Sub
```

However it only writes the value of the last control.
For example if i have 2 textboxes created, by clicking 2 times the Button5, the test2.txt contains the .Text value from the second textbox only and not the first

Is there a way to write the .Text value from every textbox, to the same text file?

Comment: what you're doing if i see this right is every time you click button5 making a new instance on your textbox ( new TextBox) that for sure will only hold the last instance which was generated with it. Try adding you're instances to a collection and then iterate through them

Comment: Very nice thought Mark thanks a lot. I will try save them in an arraylist first and then write them to a text file

Comment: Did it help you than i make an answer from my comment that you can accept or do you need some further help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're doing if i see this right is every time you click button5 making a new instance on your textbox ( new TextBox) that for sure will only hold the last instance which was generated with it. Try adding you're instances to a collection and then iterate through them